# Get the output of multiple strace calls in one file

Tags: file, output, strace

I want to get the Output of multiple strace calls in one file,
but i do not know how.

At the moment i am using:
strace -o tmpfile, but this just puts the output of one file in and then overrites the file with the new output.

Has anyone an idea, how to do this?
I hope this is no dumb question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not manage to do this via the call itself (in the Android Shell).
I just read through all files and write them to one Log file.
This solution slows the whole process down, but was the only solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

Under the bash shell use the following command

```
strace -o >(cat >>outputfile) command [args] ...
```

This will pass to the -o flag an argument that will appear like a file, but will be instead a file descriptor to the standard input of the

```
cat >>outputfile
```

process.  This process will append its input to the specified output file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use this on my android phone, so i can not use cat this way. Maybe an other idea how to realize this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strace -o somefile command`, can you just do `strace command >> somefile`? Alternatively, assuming a similar version of `strace`, my manual for `strace` indicates this should work: `strace -o "|tail -a somefile" command` (the `-o "|command"` functionality is implemented by `strace` itself, not by the shell).

Comment: The first soultion (with >>) does not work, because >> is not recognized. The Second soultion gives me a file with name: "|tail -a somefile" which contains only the last strace call.

Answer (score 0):

The strace output is on stderr, `strace 2>> outfile` did the trick for me. If you invoke strace as single command you have to call it like this: `adb -e shell "strace -p pid 2>> file"`